# Proper way to use apply_filters() with class functions?

Tags: plugin-development, filters

I want to allow my user to override a function. It's a plugin. I believe that apply_filters() can be used for this. this can be overridden by add_filter().

I am confused about how to use it.
Say if i have a class like this

```
class Example{
  public function hello(){
   $title = the_title_attribute();
   return $title;
  }
}
```

What change should I make to allow that $title to be modified? where to place the apply filter?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on you where you want to call [`apply_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/).

It can be right when you defined the `$title`:

```php
$title = apply_filters( 'my_hook', the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); // set echo to false
return $title;
```

Or in the `return` call:

```php
$title = the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ); // set echo to false
return apply_filters( 'my_hook', $title );
```

Then one can hook to the filter like so:

```php
add_filter( 'my_hook', 'some_function' );
```

PS: As @birgire pointed, `the_title_attribute()` will echo output, unless the `echo` argument is set to `false`. So be sure to use the function with the proper [parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title_attribute/#parameters).

Comment: ps: `the_title_attribute()` will echo output, unless the `echo` argument is set to `false`.

Comment: Thanks @birgire. I've added that to the answer. :)

Comment: Thank you, got it cleared