# How to use apply_filters() inside a plugin class?

Tags: php, filters

I'd like themes to be able to alter a default array of data inside a plugin class. It's currently set up like:

```
namespace Example;

class Example_Class {

    private $stuff;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->stuff = $this->set_stuff();

    }

    public function set_stuff() {

        $things = array(
            'first' => 'First',
            'second' => 'Second',
        );

        return apply_filters( 'my_cool_filter', $things );
     }

}
```

Then to test it I put this in the theme's functions.php:

```
function change_things( $things ) {

    $things = array(
        'third' => 'Third',
        'fourth' => 'Fourth',
    );

    return $things;
 }

 add_filter( 'my_cool_filter', 'change_things' );
```

However it's not working. The `$stuff` property is still getting set as the original default array, so `add_filter()` isn't having any effect. It would seem to be [the same question as this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/337867/proper-way-to-use-apply-filters-with-class-functions), but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:
The class is in a plugin and instantiated as part of the plugin loading - called from the main plugin file. The methods in the class manage settings and the main one that uses the property is hooked to `admin_init`, but if I add `die( var_dump( $this->stuff ) )` inside the constructor just after it's set, I get the original array instead of the filtered array. I think it's clear from what everyone is saying that it must be an issue of things happening in the wrong order, but don't plugins always load before the theme?

Comment: Are you sure the array isn't being filtered/changed? Because your code seems just fine. So where/how do you call the class (`new Example\Example_Class`)?

Comment: Maybe you call your class function before you add_filter

Comment: It is not the same question as the question you linked to, and `apply_filters` is being used correctly. However, we have no information about how your class is being created, when it's being created, where it's being created, or how you tested the `stuff` variable, can you edit your question and include that information?

Comment: Thanks all - good to know at least the usage is correct. I've added more info - it seems that the `do_action` must be happening before the `apply_filters` but I'm not sure how to check that. Would it throw an error if I enable wp_debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is good — you are using both `apply_filters()` and `add_filter()` correctly.

But the timing/hook does not seem correct.

> I think it's clear from what everyone is saying that it must be an issue of things happening in the wrong order, but don't plugins always load before the theme?

- Wrong order: Yes — you most likely called `apply_filters()` before the filter (`change_things()`) is added (via `add_filter()`) or that you instantiated the class `Example_Class` in the wrong place/hook (i.e. instantiated too early).
- Don't plugins always load before the theme? Yes they do, therefore you need to ensure your filter is added on-time — and the earliest hook you'd use to ensure your code runs after the *theme* is loaded would be [`after_setup_theme`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_setup_theme/):

  > ```
  > /**
  >  * Fires after the theme is loaded.
  >  *
  >  * @since 3.0.0
  >  */
  > do_action( 'after_setup_theme' );
  > ```

  See [this Codex article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) for a list of the hooks and their order of execution on a WordPress page, both admin and non-admin sides, but for an up-to-date list, try [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) or the other options [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/162862).

So for example, if you instantiated the class in `plugins_loaded`, then the property `Example_Class::$stuff` would *not* be filtered by the `change_things()`.

And here are two examples demonstrating how should and should not the class be instantiated:

- On-time/good instantiation — `admin_init` runs **after** `after_setup_theme`:

  ```php
  // In main plugin file:
  // Note: I used closure merely for testing purposes.

  add_action( 'admin_init', function () {
      require_once '/path/to/class-example-class.php';
      new Example\Example_Class;
      // the $this->stuff in the class would now be the $things returned by
      // change_things()
  } );
  ```

  And as you may have guessed it, you can use `after_setup_theme` in place of the `admin_init`. But in most plugins, they initialize things via the [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) hook which runs after WordPress setups things like the theme and current user:

  > ```
  > /**
  >  * Fires after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent.
  >  *
  >  * Most of WP is loaded at this stage, and the user is authenticated. WP continues
  >  * to load on the {@see 'init'} hook that follows (e.g. widgets), and many plugins instantiate
  >  * themselves on it for all sorts of reasons (e.g. they need a user, a taxonomy, etc.).
  >  *
  >  * If you wish to plug an action once WP is loaded, use the {@see 'wp_loaded'} hook below.
  >  *
  >  * @since 1.5.0
  >  */
  > do_action( 'init' );
  > ```
- Too-early instantiation — `plugins_loaded` runs **before** `after_setup_theme`:

  ```php
  // In main plugin file:

  add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function () {
      require_once '/path/to/class-example-class.php';
      new Example\Example_Class;
      // change_things() was not executed
  } );
  ```

Comment: Hm, okay thanks!! Good to know. I'll test it this week, I'll have to refactor things a bit.

Comment: So I'm wondering, how was your test? What was the problem and how did you fix it?

Comment: I did some brief tests but ended up changing things around. Thanks for your help though!